# Is there a Lipschiz function from $R^{n-1}$ to a spherical surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, lipschitz-functions

Let $S^{n-1}=\{x\in \mathbb R^n:||x||=1\}=\partial B_1(0)$.
I have to prove that there exists a Lipschitz function $d: \mathbb R^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$ i.e.
$$\exists L\ \forall x,y \in \mathbb R^{n-1},\ ||d(x)-d(y)||\le L||x-y||$$
My effort:

1) $S^{n-1}$ is a compact set of $\mathbb R^n$ because is colsed and bounded 
2) $S^{n-1}=\partial B_1(0)$, which is a Lipschitz domain (well known)

so I thinked to use the compactness to find a finite cover $\mathcal S$ of $S^{n-1}$, such that for every element of $S\in \mathcal S$:
$$\exists f\ \ \ A_S=f(S),\  A_S\in \mathbb R^{n-1}$$
with $A_S$ bounded and $f(\cdot)$ Lipschitz.
I cannot formalize and finish this proof and I'm wondering if it is the simplest way to proceed. Do you have any other idea? Can you improve this one?

Comment: I guess $n\ge 2$ is required and surjectivity.

Comment: Every constant map is Lipschitz

Comment: sure but you cannot define a constant map $\mathbb R^{n-1} \to \mathbb R^{n}$